# Change dynamically style in Angular with ngfor array data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, arraylist

I want to set the `width` as dynamically with the data that i am gonna take from the array. But angular doesn't let me set it with usual way. How can i handle it ?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of products">
    <div [style.width.px]="{{ item.size }}" class="Holiday"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you do not need `{{ }}` when you're using `[]`.

change `[style.width.px]="{{ item.size }}"` to `[style.width.px]="item.size"` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ngStyle` to apply dynamic styles.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of products">
    <div [ngStyle]="{ 'width' : item.size+'px' }" class="Holiday"></div>
</div>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fel5sk